# How to deploy the 'nodejs-sentiment-bot-sample' on azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, microsoft-graph-api

The [microsoftgraph/nodejs-sentiment-bot-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-sentiment-bot-sample) can run on your localhost with a self-signed certificate. What changes are necessary in order to deploy it on Azure regarding this certificate?

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Framework works with bots deployed on any cloud hosting service, as long as you have an internet-accessible endpoint and a valid SSL certificate. If you are deploying to Azure App Service, your `projectname.azurewebsites.net` is covered by the existing `*.azurewebsites.net` SSL cert, so you should not need any additional configuration.

On the other hand, if you want to host on another cloud provider, the only requirements is that you have a current and valid SSL certificate registered to your domain name.

What is meant by "current and valid"? -- Most of the checks for "current and valid" are standard checks for server SSL certificates: the Certificate Name must match the hostname, it must not be expired, it must not be listed in a CRL, it must have the correct set of EKUs, etc.

Most importantly, your SSL certificate must chain to a root certificate authority trusted by Microsoft. The latest list of these CAs is available here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31634.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-participants-v-2016-april.aspx

For more information on deploying your bot, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/deploy-bot-overview

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to deploy the example on Azure after deleting the https-options that were added during the creating of the restify server and changing the hardcoded urls that were pointing to localhost.

Comment: @Christof.Doe - Thanks for the update. Glad to hear you got it working!